# What is the average distance between two points on the perimeter of a sector?

Tags: geometry

I have seen posts about the average distance between two random points on the perimeter of a rectangle/circle. But I wasn't able to find a derivation for the average distance between two random points on the perimeter of a sector. For the perimeter, I am including both the arc and the radii. The sector is a minor sector. Does this derivation exist?

Comment: You have to integrate ig

Comment: Say the centre of the circle the sector is part of is $O$, and the arc that defines the sector goes from point $P$ to point $Q$. Are you defining the perimeter to be just the arc $PQ$ or are you including the segments $OP$ and $OQ$ as well?

Comment: @ChrisLewis For the perimeter, I am including the segments OP and OQ as well.

Comment: That's _wild_ :-). Essentially, yes, you have to parameterise the perimeter and integrate. You'll have to parameterise it piecewise, but it's made of "nice" shapes. Can you see where to go from there?